# Possible to use ERB/slim template instead of EJS (JST) after Ajax update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript, ejs, slim-lang

I've seen a lot of questions around this topic but no definitive solutions. I have a Rails 3.2 app that leverages ERB/slim and Coffeescript/EJS/Backbone. I inherited this codebase so some of these peripherals are a little over my head.

**Problem**

My `venue` view has a section that displays `tips` that were submitted to the `venue`. The list of `tips` has a "sort" function facilitated by JavaScript. The associated CoffeeScript file has event listeners for clicks on links for "recent" and "popular". On click, the JS does some work and utilizes Rails scopes to resort the list. I'm building out this `tips` list to include a little more data, specifically including the Rails helper `time_ago_in_words`. The original code updated the div containing the tips using a JST/EJS template in the Javascripts/templates asset directory.

These are the specific problems I encounter:

1. If I add .erb to the file chain (after updating the EJS interpreter to look for a different evaluation and interpolation pattern as to not conflict with ERB), I can evaluate basic Ruby expressions. The partial, however, fails to have access to the same `tip` variable that the JavaScript references. I know this is because Rails is server side and JS is client side. Consensus seems to be no, but is there a way to get that data to Rails?
2. While basic Ruby expressions can be evaluated (`Time.now`, for example), Rails helpers such as `time_ago_in_words` fail, complaining that the method is undefined for the class, though I am absolutely passing in the proper date object. Can Rails/helpers not be evaluated in this .EJS.ERB chain?
3. I can circumvent all of these problems if there is a way to reference the original ERB/slim partial used on load after the sort is performed. Is this possible? Right now the Coffeescript file called uses `render` and `JST` to call on the EJS template. Is it possible to somehow reference the original partial but with the updated sort?

Here's the relevant code.

```
  ##show.html.erb (venue)##
  #tips
    p.sort.span4
      | Sort by: 
      = link_to 'Recent', '#', class: 'selected', id: 'sort-tips-recent'
      |  | 
      = link_to 'Popularity', '#', id: 'sort-tips-popularity'
    #tip-list
      = render resource.tips.by_recent


##tip_list_view.js.coffee##
class CS.TipListView extends Backbone.View
  el: "#tip_module"

  events:
    "click #sort-tips-recent": "sortByRecent"
    "click #sort-tips-popularity": "sortByPopularity"

  initialize: ->
    console.log("ERROR: View must be initialized with a model") unless @model
    @model.bind('reset', @render)

  render: =>
    tips = @model.map (tip) -> JST['templates/tip'](tip: tip)
    @$('#tip-list').html(tips.join("\n"))

  sortByRecent: (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    @model.enableSortRecent()
    @updateSelectedFilter('recent')

  sortByPopularity: (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    @model.enableSortPopularity()
    @updateSelectedFilter('popularity')

  updateSelectedFilter: (sort) ->
    @$('p.sort a').removeClass('selected')
   @$("p.sort a#sort-tips-#{sort}").addClass('selected')


##tip.jst.ejs.erb (called from tip_list_view.js.coffee after sort change##
<div class="tip">
  <p class="tip-author">
    <$= tip.get('user').username $>
  </p>
  <p class="tip-timestamp">
    Eventually, time goes here
  </p>
  <p class="tip-likes pull-right">
    <$= tip.upvoteCountText() $>
  </p>
  <p id="<$= tip.domId() $>">
    <$= tip.get('text') $>
    <$ if(tip.get('can_upvote')) { $>
      <a href="<$= tip.upvoteUrl() $>">upvote</a>
    <$ } $>
  </p>
<div>
```

Definitely at a loss here - any and all help is greatly appreciated. Let me know if there is any other detail or code I can provide for background. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The solution is seemingly a bit hacky, particularly with the update method. And with this, I'm still unclear on how to get the data that the JS can access, for example the created_at, and pass it into an evaluation for time_ago_in_words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your ejs.erb, Rails is generating the template, but has no idea what you will use it for. Then your Backbone app is fetching the tip from Rails via ajax, and populate the model accordingly. Then it's your backbone app that populates and renders the template. Rails cannot chime in here, at least not in this configuration where backbone expects json and then renders the template. Everything is happening in the front-end.

The only thing you can do is ask Rails to give you the result of your helpers inside the json. I am guessing you have a Tip.rb model and it should implement:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper
...
def as_json(options = {})
  {
    :name => self.name,
    ... (all the model attributes that you want to expose)
    :date_age => time_ago_in_words self.created_at
  }
end
```

That being said, I would def use a client side solution, also because: http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/105-not-use-time_ago_in_words

Comment: This works brilliantly, thank you! I also really appreciate the pointer to the best practices idea. Given how new I am (particularly to JS), I'm going to stick with this workaround for now since performance is not yet a concern for me but will later refactor to best practices using a client-side solution. Thanks again for the help, really really appreciated!